# Exporting Code to pdf

Tags: export

I want to export Mathematica Input and Output code to pdf (for usage with Latex). I select the cells and use "Save selection as". However, the font size of the pdfs is to large for Latex usage and if I decrease it, the frontend becomes unreadable. Also, the pdfs don't fit on the page. My questions are:

- What exactly do I have to do to have the pdf-export use, say, font size 10, while the Frontend continues to use 13?
- How can I set the width of the pdfs generated?
- As a side question: Can one tell Mathematica somehow a fixed directory to save to? Manually chosing the directory each time is rather painful.

Note that I am aware that there are related questions already. But none of these seems to have much effect on the results of my exports.

Comment: Actually, it seems that my Mathematica 9 does not use the Printout environment in this case and thus changes to this environment have no effect. CurrentValue[PrintingStyleEnvironment] gives Printout though. Very strange.