# How to set width of exported pdf/eps

Tags: export, pdf-format, cells, pagelayout

I want to export a cell's input (the text of the command) as pdf/eps. I have used

```
Export["cell.pdf", cells[[1]]]
```

It works fine, however, I would like to change the width after which a line break appears. When exporting whole notebook as pdf, I can change margins of the page and the line breaks are performed accordingly, however, it does not affect this kind of export. This export does not seem to follow neither working nor printout styles.

Is there any way how to force a particular width of the exported pdf while having the same size of letters?

I tried `ImageFormattingWidth` as in [this example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFormattingWidth.html) of what I precisely want (but without `Rasterize` in pdf), it had no effect.

I am aware of partially duplicating [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63730/exporting-code-to-pdf) which, however, have not been answered and do not include any examples.

I am using *Mathematica* 10.4.

An example of `cells[[1]]` is

```
Cell[BoxData[  RowBox[{RowBox[{"g", "=", 
  RowBox[{"{", 
    RowBox[{RowBox[{"{", 
        RowBox[{RowBox[{"1", "-", 
            FractionBox[
             RowBox[{RowBox[{"2", " ", "M", " ", "r"}], "-", 
               SuperscriptBox["Q", "2"]}], "\[Rho]2"]}], ",", 
          RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ",", "0", ",", 
          FractionBox[
           RowBox[{"a", " ", 
             RowBox[{"(", 
               RowBox[{RowBox[{"2", " ", "M", " ", "r"}], "-", 
                SuperscriptBox["Q", "2"]}], ")"}], " ", 
             SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"Sin", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}],
               "2"]}], "\[Rho]2"]}], "}"}], ",", 
      RowBox[{"{", 
        RowBox[{RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ",", "0", ",", "0", ",", 
          RowBox[{"a", " ", 
            SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"Sin", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}], 
             "2"]}]}], "}"}], ",", 
      RowBox[{"{", 
        RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", RowBox[{"-", "\[Rho]2"}], ",",
           "0"}], "}"}], ",", 
      RowBox[{"{", 
        RowBox[{FractionBox[
           RowBox[{"a", " ", 
             RowBox[{"(", 
               RowBox[{RowBox[{"2", " ", "M", " ", "r"}], "-", 
                SuperscriptBox["Q", "2"]}], ")"}], " ", 
             SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"Sin", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}],
               "2"]}], "\[Rho]2"], ",", 
          RowBox[{"a", " ", 
            SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"Sin", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}], 
             "2"]}], ",", "0", ",", 
          RowBox[{"-", 
            FractionBox[
             RowBox[{"\[CapitalSigma]2", " ", 
               SuperscriptBox[
                RowBox[{"Sin", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}], "2"]}], 
             "\[Rho]2"]}]}], "}"}]}], "}"}]}], ";"}]], "Input",  CellChangeTimes -> {{3.67481*10^9, 3.67481*10^9}}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `PageWidth` option inside of the `Cell`'s code. Assuming that a variable `cell` contains the raw `Cell` expression from your question, it is as simple as follows:

```
Export["cell.pdf", Append[cell, PageWidth -> 2000]]
```

If you have a `CellObject`, you can get the code of the `Cell` with `NotebookRead` and then proceed as above:

```
Export["cell.pdf", Append[NotebookRead@Cells[][[1]], PageWidth -> 2000]]
```

Here is how exported PDF looks when opened in Adobe Acrobat:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much! The info about `Append` was also useful :)